# Running query that restarts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a MySql database through phpmyadmin and am working on building a query to total some values.

In EXCEL the formula looks like this =IF(AND(P6=P5,B6=B5),SUM(H5+F6),F6)

That formula is put in the H column

P Column is a class identifier.   B Column is their registration number.   H Column is their total points.   F column is the point value of their entry.

It works great in excel.   But having some troubles in the syntax for SQL.

I know that first I need to sort the file so that everything comes through in the correct order, got that.  But from that point on I am clueless.

If a more in depth explanation is needed for my excel code I can do that, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you need running total with some "partitioning" or rows. It seems that in MySql you need to do some "hacking" with variables, as analytic functions are not available in this database.

Following query will do it. It uses three variables - @rollingsum to store sum of F column, and @prevP and @prevB variables to store previous value of B and P columns)

```
SELECT s.p, s.b, s.f, s.rollingSum FROM 
(
SELECT  p, 
        b, 
        f, 
        IF( p=@prevP AND b=@prevB,
        @rollingsum := @rollingsum + f,
        @rollingsum := f )  as rollingSum,
        @prevP := p,
        @prevB := b
FROM      test_table p, (SELECT @rollingsum := 0, @prevP := '', @prevB := '') r 
ORDER BY  p,b ) s
```

Example:

Source data:

```
P   B   F
1   1   10
1   1   10
1   2   10
1   2   10
1   2   10
2   2   10
2   2   10
2   2   10
```

Result for the above query (rollingsum column is your H column - total points in your excel):

```
P   B   F   ROLLINGSUM
1   1   10  10
1   1   10  20
1   2   10  10
1   2   10  20
1   2   10  30
2   2   10  10
2   2   10  20
2   2   10  30
```

Comment: That looks perfect!   I am away from my computer, but I will give it a go when I am home tonight.   It looks to be exactly what I was needing.   Thank you!

Comment: Okay getting much closer.  The only things I need to change is that I think the ORDER BY needs to be one of the first things run.  Because these files are not always in correct order.   And I need it to set the rollingsum value to the total points column.    Here is what it looks like now with my values:

Comment: SELECT Test.Class_Subset, Test.RegNum, Test.Points,Test.Total_Points, Test.rollingsum, Test.Date_Earned
FROM (

SELECT Class_Subset,Total_Points, RegNum, Points, Date_Earned, IF( Class_Subset = @prevSub
AND RegNum = @prevNum , @rollingsum := @rollingsum + `Points` , @rollingsum := `Points` ) AS rollingSum, @prevSub := Class_Subset, @prevNum := RegNum
FROM Test, (

SELECT @rollingsum :=0, @prevSub := '', @prevNum := ''
)r
ORDER BY RegNum, Class_Subset, Date_Earned, Total_Points
)Test

Comment: Actually it looks like the ORDER BY is working correctly.  I don't understand why, I thought it would need to be at the beginning.  But I can't get the @rollingsum to transfer over to the Total_Points column.   I have tried a few different UPDATE commands in different places

Comment: Updating is diffrent story ;).

Comment: Haha that's what I thought.   How big of a headache am I in for that?

Comment: Do you really want to update this table ? I would recommend to create NEW table and insert records from old table with calculated total_points. CREATE TABLE test_total LIKE test;
 INSERT INTO test_total SELECT .... FROM ...;

Comment: Well my first thought was updating the original table.   But creating a new table would work also.     I am a little fuzzy on what I would need to do though.   Jeez, I am gonna owe you a beer after all this

Comment: Where in the code should I put the insert command?  If I put it at the end it just comes up with the last value the variable had

Comment: The last should be query (SELECT) from the newly created table. Look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fcf2/6

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us much detail about your table structure, so I am supposing you have records with SOME_ID = 5 and SOME_ID = 6.
With this data, one possible SQL statement would be:

```
select 
    (select T1.B from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) as B_PREVIOUS,
    (select T1.F from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) as F_PREVIOUS,
    (select T1.H from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) as H_PREVIOUS,
    (select T1.P from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) as P_PREVIOUS,
    B as B_CURRENT, F as F_CURRENT, H as H_CURRENT, P as P_CURRENT,
    case when
        (select T1.B from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) = B
        and
        (select T1.P from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) = P then
          (select T1.H from SOME_TABLE T1 where T1.SOME_ID = :PREVIOUS_ID) + F
  else
          F
  end as RESULT
from SOME_TABLE
where SOME_ID = :CURRENT_ID
```

Of course the only needed returning column is RESULT. I am returning the other only for debugging purpose.

Hope this helps you!

**EDITED:** updated to reflect @Ben notes on performance degradation due to repeatedly searching the current record

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my file:  http://nadacforum.com/Points.png        I think the above would work.   but the only problem is that I need something that can look at the RegNum without me entering it.   The big files are almost a million records long.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I am correctly understanding your problem. If you need to process one record, taken the previous one as reference, maybe my updated answer now will give your the expected results. Any way, this solution work for one ID at a time. If you need to dynamically find the previous ID, you can add "where SOME_ID = (select max(ID) from SOME_TABLE where ID < :CURRENT_ID), or something like that.

Comment: Are you really suggesting the OP does 8 index scans? Doesn't that seem a little excessive?

Comment: Of course is excessive, but we should only optimize code that works. When "Chris Nelson" tell us if that works, we can help him optimize this statement, but for now I am curious to know from him (or from any other) if that works, and if not I would appreciate to see an alternative statement.

Comment: @Jeferson, I believe you're taking the maxim too far. As you're already selecting from `some_table where some_id = :current_id` you can remove 4 of them and have exactly the same result and a lot less chance of making an error as you need to type a lot less.

Comment: Ok. Now I see your point. But it is true only after the last update, that will work only if "Chris Nelson" tell us if that is what he wants. Anyway I will update the sample code to reflect your notes.

Comment: @Ben: Done! Feel free to edit my answer if you still see some room for improvements.

Comment: I actually used the other example given above and it worked good.  I used it because it was a little simpler so I understood it better